What exactly is the postgresql BPCHAR data type suppose to have different then VARCHAR?
I am trying to understand the purpose of the bpchar data type in postgresql, according to the official documentation the difference is suppose to be that it is blank-trimmed, even though the bp in bpchar stands for Blank-Padding which already confuses me.
I tried a simple test in python with asyncpg where i save and read back a string of blank spaces and both varchar and bpchar prints the blank spaces correctly showing that they have been written in the database and that no trimming has occurred. I also tried with a string made of a word surrounded by a few blank spaces and the result is the same.
Here is the code with varchar:
import asyncpg
import uvloop

async def main():
    print("varchar")
    # Establish a connection to an existing database named "test"
    # as a "postgres" user.
    conn = await asyncpg.connect('postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/test')
    # Execute a statement to create a new table.
    await conn.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE users(
            id serial PRIMARY KEY,
            name varchar
        )
    ''')
    # Insert a record into the created table.
    await conn.execute('''
        INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES($1)
    ''', '      ')
    # Select a row from the table.
    row = await conn.fetchrow(
        'SELECT * FROM users')
    print(f"x{row.get("name")}x")
    # Close the connection.
    await conn.close()

uvloop.run(main())

Which output:
varchar
x      x

And the same thing with bpchar:
import asyncpg
import uvloop

async def main():
    print("bpchar")
    # Establish a connection to an existing database named "test"
    # as a "postgres" user.
    conn = await asyncpg.connect('postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/test')
    # Execute a statement to create a new table.
    await conn.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE users(
            id serial PRIMARY KEY,
            name bpchar
        )
    ''')
    # Insert a record into the created table.
    await conn.execute('''
        INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES($1)
    ''', '      ')
    # Select a row from the table.
    row = await conn.fetchrow(
        'SELECT * FROM users')
    print(f"x{row.get("name")}x")
    # Close the connection.
    await conn.close()

uvloop.run(main())

Which output:
bpchar
x      x

As you can see, both varchar and bpchar results in the same non-trimmed output.
Am i doing something wrong or is the documentation unclear?

Form the linked documentation: "The type name varchar is an alias for character varying, while bpchar (with length specifier) and char are aliases for character.". So, based on that it seems that bpchar is in fact a blank padded string, confusing wording notwithstanding.

Just use TEXT.

The purpose of bpchar (or character) is to satisfy the SQL standard. It does not have any practical value and is considered harmful (see the "tip" in the documentation). Don't use it.
You will notice the difference to varchar(n) if you concatenate strings or calculate the length().
